# Can connect to Cassandra cluster using OpsCenter but not DevCenter or via Java

Tags: java, cassandra, ubuntu-13.10, opscenter

Cassandra noob here. I've done the online training which didn't need more than a localhost connection. Now I've pulled out some old computers and set them up as a cluster, however I can't connect to them via DevCenter or using the Java Driver.

I used OpsCenter to set up the cluster hoping that I would not have to do any manual configuration, but it seems that some manual configuration will be required.

I used OpsCenter 4.0.3 to create a Community 2.0.3 cluster with four nodes. All four nodes are joined to the cluster. OpsCenter sees them all and shows them as Active. All four nodes are running Ubuntu Desktop 13.10. I have successfully added a keyspace using the OpsCenter Schema tab.

Nmap shows that none of the nodes has port 9042 open, so it seems to me that it's a problem with the client side agents not listening on the port.

At the suggestion of someone from DataStax I edited the cassandra.yaml file on one of the nodes (the seed node, as it happens) and set the rpc_address to the node ip address (ie: 192.168.0.123). I restarted the node from OpsCenter, but there was no effect.

I then edited cassandra.yaml and changed the listen_address to be the node address, and restarted the node from OpsCenter, again to no avail.

Clearly I have missed a step somewhere along the line. Anyone who has successfully started a Cassandra cluster know what I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Edit cassandra.yaml, find the line that has rpc_address, un comment it and set it to:
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

if you used datastax to install cassandra you can find cassandra.yaml in /etc/cassandra

Answer (score 1):

Check that the following settings are on (at least one of ) your C* node:

1. `start_native_transport: true`
2. `native_transport_port: 9042`
3. `rpc_address: IP` -- where the IP is something you can ping from the machine running DevCenter.

Once you've restarted the node make sure you can actually connect to it: `telnet IP 9042`. If you cannot than most probably you haven't edited the right `cassandra.yaml`.